# SQL Server stored procedure deadlock

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure is called by the periodic job in SQL Server 2008R2 and it always gets the deadlock:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID XX) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

The procedure is as below and I have replaced the variable name. It gets one parameter `@Time` and will read data from a table `myTable` and a view `myView`. There isn’t any index on `myView`.

Also it will call another procedure to update another table `mySecondTable`.

Any suggestion? MAXDOP? Index on the view? Or the problem is on the cursor?

Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_Schedule    
    @TIME datetime = NULL
AS
    DECLARE @localVar1 varchar(50)
    DECLARE @localVar2 varchar(50)
    DECLARE @localVar3 int
    DECLARE @localVar4 varchar(50)
    DECLARE @localVar10 varchar(50)   
    DECLARE @localVar11 varchar(50)   
    DECLARE @localVar12 varchar(50)   
    DECLARE @localVar13 int   
    DECLARE @flag INT   

    Select @flag = Value   
    From myTabe   
    Where condition1 = ‘xxxx’ and condition2 = ‘xxxx’ and condition3 = ‘xxxx’   

   DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD    
   FOR   
      SELECT 
          P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, MAX(P7) AS C1, MAX(P8) AS S1,   
          MAX(P9), MAX(P10), MAX(P11), MAX(P12), MAX(P13), 
          MAX(P14), MAX(P15)   
      FROM myTabe   
      WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -1, @TIME) AND @TIME   
      GROUP BY P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P1   
      ORDER BY P5, P6   

   OPEN MY_CURSOR   

   FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR   
INTO @localVar1, @localVar2, @localVar3, @localVar4, @starttime, @stoptime,    @localVar5, @localVar6, @localVar7, @localVar8, @localVar9, @localVar10, @localVar11, @localVar12, @localVar13

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN
      IF (@flag = 1 )   
      BEGIN  
          EXEC anotherPROCEDURE @localVar2, @localVar3, @localVar4,
                                @localVar1, @starttime, @stoptime, 
                                @localVar13, @localVar7, @localVar8,
                                @localVar9, @localVar10, @localVar11, 
                                @localVar12
      END   
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         EXEC anotherPROCEDURE @localVar2, @localVar3, @localVar4,  
                               @localVar1, @starttime, @stoptime, 
                               @localVar6, @localVar7, @localVar8, 
                               @localVar9, @localVar10, @localVar11, 
                               @localVar12
      END

      FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR
        INTO    @localVar1, @localVar2, @localVar3, @localVar4, @starttime, @stoptime, @localVar5, @localVar6, @localVar7, @localVar8, @localVar9,   @localVar10, @localVar11, @localVar12, @localVar13
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR   
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: I think it largely depends on what "anotherProcedure" is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It is too little details to make any practical judgement but I'd move out of row-by-row processing to set-based approach. I'd rewrite procedures to take @TIME parameter and process all the same records as in MY_CURSOR in one go. It is much more beneficial from locking (and deadlocking) point of view. And it should be much faster.